# How to make pandas show the entire dataframe without cropping it by columns?

Tags: pandas, ipython, jupyter-lab

I am trying to represent cubic spline interpolation information for function f(x) as a dataframe.
When trying to print into a spyder, I find that the columns are being cut off. When trying to reproduce the output in Jupiter Lab, I got the same thing.
[image: screenshot]
When I ran in ipython via terminal I got the desired full dataframe output.
I searched the integnet and tried the pandas commands setting options pd.set_options(), but nothing came of it.

I attach a screenshot with the output in ipython.

Comment: do not use the `print(df)` statement but just `df`.

Comment: Thanks. But it does not solve problems. Yes, it work, but work only in jupyter and if call df  in separate cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Juputer can use:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
```

and instead of

```
print(dataframe)
```

use of in anyway place

```
display(HTML(dataframe.to_html()))
```

This will create a nice table.
[image]

Unfortunately, this will not work in the spyder. So you can try to adjust the width of the ipython were suggested. But in most cases this will make the output poorly or unreadable.

After trying the dataframe methods, I found what appears to be a cropping setting.

In Spyder I used:

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
print(dataframe)
```

This method explains why increasing max_column didn't help me previously.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* specify a maximum number for rows or columns using `pd.set_options(display.max_columns=1000)`

But you don't *have* to set an arbitrary value, but rather use `None` instead to make sure every size will be covered.

For rows, use:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

And for columns, use:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Comment: Isn't this still constrained by `display.width` even for unlimited cols?

Answer (score 0):

It is a result of the display width, which by default is smaller. You can use the following `set_option()`:

```
pd.set_option(display.width=1000) #make huge
```

You may also have to raise max columns but it should be smart enough to adjust automatically after you make width bigger:

```
pd.set_option(display.max_columns=None)
```

Comment: Thanks.
pd.set_option("display.width", 1000) 
Turn off cropping.

Comment: Glad it works. If this helped to solve your problem consider [marking it as an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This helps others users of stack overflow find the answers they need.